# OpenRefine : split a cell based on the a string of 5 numbers (postal code)

Tags: regex, openrefine

I am new to OpenRefine and GREL.
In a address row, I am trying to extract the city and the postal code.
The row will typically contains : 12 rue du Paradis 75012 Paris

I'd like to split this row starting from the 5 digit number (75012). After I could easily extract the city.

In the command "Split into several columns", what Regular expression would you put (or is it another command)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The 'split into several columns' takes a regular expression as an argument to specify the separator to be used when doing the split. This is probably not what you need in this case - since there isn't a common expression for the separator.

Instead you would probably be better using the "Add column based on this column" option and then using a 'match' function to create the new column. The 'match' takes a regular expression as an argument, but allows you to capture the output - so you can use this to do pattern matching in a string. In this case for example you could use something like:

```
value.match(/.*\s+(\d{5})\s+(.*)/)
```

This would capture the 5 digit number and the city in an array:

```
["75012","Paris"]
```

You could then use this to create the values you want in the new column, or in two new columns. E.g.:

```
value.match(/.*\s+(\d{5})\s+(.*)/)[0]
```

will get the number